# When i am doing migration, the netwrok name is ganache instead of development and multiple errors are there

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration, error

```
D:\>truffle migrate --reset

Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Compiling .\contracts\Migrations.sol
> Artifacts written to D:\build\contracts
> Compiled successfully using:
   - solc: 0.5.16+commit.9c3226ce.Emscripten.clang



Starting migrations...
======================
> Network name:    'ganache'
> Network id:      5777
> Block gas limit: 0x6691b7


1_initial_migration.js
======================

   Replacing 'Migrations'
   ----------------------
   > transaction hash:    0x4a691a6dcbd5a8cf87f274c0d13d5eebf6d3f8c52f833f49dc01054a093bc92d
   > Blocks: 0            Seconds: 0
   > contract address:    0xa6711a857E1DFF44D867baB8F00764A45DB3A978
   > block number:        3
   > block timestamp:     1584911889
   > account:             0xF6C0D0d48706A7749Ce3EB3889372Ab97d6827ab
   > balance:             99.99162066
   > gas used:            188483
   > gas price:           20 gwei
   > value sent:          0 ETH
   > total cost:          0.00376966 ETH


   > Saving migration to chain.
   > Saving artifacts
   -------------------------------------
   > Total cost:          0.00376966 ETH


2_deploy_contracts.js
=====================

Error: Migration D:\migrations\2_deploy_contracts.js invalid or does not take any parameters
    at Migration._load (C:\Users\LEILA-LAPTOP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\migrate\migration.js:51:1)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at Migration.run (C:\Users\LEILA-LAPTOP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\migrate\migration.js:167:1)
    at Object.runMigrations (C:\Users\LEILA-LAPTOP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\migrate\index.js:148:1)
    at Object.runFrom (C:\Users\LEILA-LAPTOP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\migrate\index.js:110:1)
    at Object.runAll (C:\Users\LEILA-LAPTOP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\migrate\index.js:114:1)
    at Object.run (C:\Users\LEILA-LAPTOP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\migrate\index.js:79:1)
    at runMigrations (C:\Users\LEILA-LAPTOP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\core\lib\commands\migrate.js:253:1)
    at C:\Users\LEILA-LAPTOP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\core\lib\commands\migrate.js:218:1
Truffle v5.1.18 (core: 5.1.18)
Node v13.11.0
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to override default network with `--network <NETWORK_NAME>`.

```
truffle migration --network devel
```